# FeynArts: how to generate all the Feynman graphs for a given order of perturbation theory?

Tags: feyncalc

I am totally new to FeynArts Mathematica package and I am wondering if there is an opportunity to generate all (connected) Feynman graphs for a given order of perturbation theory?

What I really want to do is to choose a theory (Lagrangian), for example, QED, and see all the diagrams which appear in different orders of perturbation theory. So I don't want to fix ingoing and outgoing fields like one should do when using `InsertFields`. Is it possible to do this with FeynArts? or how to solve such a problem with help of some other tools?

Thank you!

Comment: May I suggest contacting the author of FeynArts directly (http://www.feynarts.de)?  You may get a quick answer to your question directly from him.